# "unchecked conversion" by Vector

Tags: java, vector

I get a comiler warning (unchecked conversion) from this code line:

```
Vector<String> input = rgw.exec("input/get");
```

The method "rgw" is an external class, which i have to use. Is there any chance to avoid this warning?

Comment: What is the return type of `exec()`? I guess `Vector` without type declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If that method returns the raw type `Vector`, you'll need to suppress the warning manually.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Vector<String> input = rwc.exec("input/get");
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an older Java class that doesn't use generics.

Write it this way and see if that helps:

```
Vector input - rgw.exec("input/get");
```

The fact that is uses the JDK 1.0 vintage `Vector`, when the more modern `ArrayList` is preferred, tells you a lot.

Comment: but this will give warning to use generics.

Comment: It's good that you're being so diligent, and the annotation looks like a good solution, but it's just a warning.

Comment: @duffymo I just can't stand warnings. In my mental world, they are classified as being even worse than compiler errors. Those mean yellow symbols and rectangles in eclipse make my brain hurt. :D

Comment: That's to be admired.  Good for you.  I meant it as an observation, not a criticism.  Keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an explicit cast:

```
Vector<String> input = (Vector<String>) rgw.exec("input/get");
```

Comment: This will also produce a warning. ;)

Comment: @pchris You **will** have to suppress the warning, there will always be one, no matter how you do it with those old libraries that don't use generics...